# inline css for a react component without a new file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How do I apply style to my table Component

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>type</th>
            <th>value</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td>water</td>
            <td>true</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>def</td>
            <td>fire</td>
            <td>false</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
```

without create a new seperate file of css in react? I can do import `'./table.css'` and inside table.css I have this

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px;
}
```

but how do I do it without a `.css` file? Either I want to apply style inline to every single DOM tag like

`style={{'border':'1px solid'}}`

Comment: I think you have to do inline for every single selector. There is no better way. You can define let commonStyle = { border: '1px solid' } to reuse it and easier to modify it later.

Comment: @dnp1204 so it seems like I have to create a table.css?

Comment: I think so. Hope you can find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to prefer inline css.

Alternative there are 4 ways check them out here

https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
      <table style={tableStyle}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style={tableStyle}>name</th>
            <th style={tableStyle}>type</th>
            <th style={tableStyle}>value</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style={tableStyle}>abc</td>
            <td style={tableStyle}>water</td>
            <td style={tableStyle}>true</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style={tableStyle}>def</td>
            <td style={tableStyle}>fire</td>
            <td style={tableStyle}>false</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
  const tableStyle =  {
    border: 1
};
```

Comment: that would apply style to the specific table base from the criteria stated above , he want to style all the tables across the project :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `styled-component`. The detailed document here: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics
Your can refer as below, you can write your traditional css line in side the TableFrame variable

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
const TableFrame = styled.table`
  border: 1px;
  margin: 1em;
  th {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
`;
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TableFrame>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>type</th>
            <th>value</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td>water</td>
            <td>true</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>def</td>
            <td>fire</td>
            <td>false</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </TableFrame>
    )
  }
```